# Vuejs Default object is not updating dom data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vuejs2, vue-component

I have set categories array as in data of vuejs.

`data:{ categories : [], }`

After that, using ajax call i am updating categories with `response.data.categories`. And it creates a hierarchical recursive array.

I am using the Recursive component and displaying table.
Now in this table i am doing some calculation of percentage based on dropdown change event.

For change event i am calling method calculate and all things works.
But i have the logic like to get this percentage of each row of categories, once the total of column set it counts each `(rowtotal/main_total)*100`

In Vuejs i have created one method to calculate each row using for loop. Here is my function,
[image: 1]

In this function I am recursively calling `this.categories` function and creating a new array once it creates i am again assign the new array to `this.categories`.

I am calling this function when i a perform change event from dropdown.
[image: 2]

Now the percentage calculates but the thing is main this.categories object updates with new correct values but in the DOM where i have displayed this percentage its not updating.

Actual object values comes when again i change dropdown of each row. But at the same it is not updating all rows values as in `this.categories` have already latest values.
In dom its not updating.

Please help to get some idea. As i am stuck into this from last two. Let me know if there is i am missing i can solve this.

Comment: If you could share the code in the sandbox or github, it is easier for people to help you out :)

Comment: you can see the images which is attached in question.

Comment: the images are not showing and it is always best to add code snippets than images

Comment: Can you please share the code instead of posting images of it? I would try to help you, but I won't type the code off of your images.